# Paypal REST AVS/CV2 codes

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal REST API via **rest-api-sdk-java** and **would like to ask whether it is possible to get AVS/CVV match results in the response (or error object).**

I did couple of tests (with sandbox and negative testing turned on) according to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/ (parts "Testing AVS errors" and "Testing CVV code"):

1. Payment request with billing address street **"123 AVS_A Street"** results in **INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR**:

   ```
   {
     "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
     "debug_id": "baf56174e98c8",
     "message": "An internal service error has occurred",
     "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"
   }
   ```
2. The same payment request with billing address street **"123 AVS_M Street"** results in successful sale.

**Is INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR expected error in such scenario (AVS_A) ? Is there any way how to get "raw AVS code" instead of INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR or CREDIT_CARD_REJECTED?**

My request payload:

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "number": "4446283280247004",
          "type": "visa",
          "expire_month": 11,
          "expire_year": 2018,
          "cvv2": "888",
          "first_name": "Susan",
          "last_name": "Wagner",
          "billing_address": {
            "line1": "123 AVS_A Street",
            "line2": "Billing Address Line 2",
            "city": "London",
            "country_code": "GB",
            "postal_code": "W1T 2BU",
            "state": "",
            "phone": "12345"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "GBP",
        "total": "3.55",
        "details": {
          "shipping": "0.00",
          "subtotal": "3.55",
          "tax": "0.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "T-Shirt XYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

And one more question: Is it possible to use advanced Fraud Management Filters on Sandbox environment? I'm using Pro test account but still can't use the filters (nothing happens when I click "upgrade now" button):

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_rc-manage

Answer (score 2):

looking at the debug id, the test did work - sort of -

Internal Sandbox API Error is 10555 - Filter Decline

--> https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

The transaction was declined because of a merchant risk filter for AVS. Specifically, the merchant has set the filter to decline transactions when the AVS returns a partial match.

So you've likely enabled the AVS fraud management filter on the sandbox account.

Obviously, there should be a proper error message and not just an internal service error, but it looks like the error hasn't been mapped yet.

Will follow up with the PP Devs to report & fix it ;)

As for AVS / CVV response within REST - there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the AVS/CVV response of the issuing bank just yet.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The strange thing is that I can't configure any "Advanced Fraud Management Filters" in my profile as they are greyed out and "Upgrade Now" button doesn't work. Is that known issue or just problem with my account? http://i.imgur.com/hBq3vB7.png

Comment: Huh, so here's what's going on:

Your standard profile will have basic Fraud Management Filters and Advanced Filters, for which PayPal charges a certain amount. If you do not sign up, the standard FMF settings will apply - and the default is to deny a non-match. Let me check what's up with Upgrade button. That one should work.

Comment: Confirmed - the Advanced FMF filters should be enabled automatically in SB when Pro is enabled. 
For now, please create a "US-Business Pro" Account through "developer.paypal.com --> Applications --> Sandbox Testing" to get access to the advanced fraud filter settings

Comment: OK I can confirm that with US Business Pro test account I can edit Advanced Fraud Filters. I would like to ask you one more thing: Are the filters taken into account when "Negative Testing" is turned on? e.g. when street contains AVS_A and Partial Match Filter is configured to flag such transaction.

Comment: Good to hear! I filed a bug in the meantime :(   

The filters are taken into account - that's why your test failed in the first place - 

to be honest, I haven't had a chance to test negative testing with REST, but it does seem to work.

if the filters don't fire (I'm guessing you'll see a lot of internal service errors), please let PayPal know under paypal.com/mts

Comment: The REST API doesn't return any AVS codes which kind of sucks.  You have to log into your Paypal account to view them.  This is a real pain for us. The REST API allows for SKU but no AVS code, the classic API has AVS reponses but no SKU insertion. AGH!